# Como fazer a IDE se comunicar com o xDebug dentro de um container (docker)?

Tags: ide, phpstorm, xdebug, docker

Tenho uma rede de containers criada com `docker-compose`. As configurações do xDebug são passadas em parte pelo arquivo `.yml` e em parte por um arquivo `.ini` consumido pelo PHP.

Sei que o xdebug está instalado corretamente no container porque ele aparece no `phpinfo()` e modifica os outputs de erros. Sei também, pelos logs de acesso, que o container enxerga as conexões vindas do `host` no IP `172.18.0.1`, que é um IP interno da rede criada pelo Docker (na minha rede os IPs são `192.168.x.x`).

No arquivo hosts do meu computador eu crio entradas no formato `127.0.0.1    example.com` pra acessar o site pelo navegador. Tudo ok, exceto que o PhpStorm nunca recebe informações do Xdebug, mesmo com as mais diversas confiurações, mesmo com a configuração atual - que teoricamente se conectaria de volta a qualquer IP que tenha um debugger ligado:

```
[Xdebug]
xdebug.idekey = PHPSTORM
xdebug.default_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.remote_host = 172.18.0.1
xdebug.remote_log = /var/log/remote.log
```

Se entendi bem o funcionamento do xdebug, o que falta agora é uma forma dele enviar (de dentro do container) as informações de depuração para `172.18.0.1:9000` e essas informações serem recebidas no meu computador (`192.168.x.x:9000`). Como fazer essa ponte?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pesquisando um pouco mais descobri que a instrução `xdebug.remote_host` na verdade seta um header `X-HTTP-FORWARD-FOR`, que é tudo que é preciso pra dizer ao xdebug a qual IP se conectar. Com alguns testes a mais descobri que ele consegue se conectar ao IP da Ponte de Rede. Essa ponte foi criada automaticamente quando eu configurei o Hyper-V para funcionar com o Docker.

Então com essa mudança as configurações finais ficaram assim:

```
[Xdebug]
xdebug.idekey = PHPSTORM
xdebug.default_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 0
# este é o IP da ponte de rede
xdebug.remote_host = 192.168.25.125
xdebug.remote_log = /var/log/xdebug/remote.log
```

e o log do xdebug agora mostra

```
Log opened at 2017-03-13 13:18:41
I: Connecting to configured address/port: 192.168.25.125:9000.
I: Connected to client. :-)
```

Isso quer dizer que a conexão já estava sendo aceita pela ponte. Então foi só configurar o PHPStorm para atender às chamadas de depuração do servidor "remoto": **Run > Start Listening to PHP Debug Connections**